# Where is it stated in scripture that individual jivathma is not the doer?

Tags: atma, jiva

I wanted to know where all is it written in the scriptures that individual is not the doer.

Comment: Bhagavad Gita 3.27 : All activities are carried out by the three modes of material nature. But in ignorance, the soul, deluded by false identification with the body, thinks itself to be the doer.      .

Bhagavad Gita 5.8 – 5.9: Those steadfast in this karm yog, always think, “I am not the doer,” even while engaged in seeing, hearing, touching, smelling, moving, sleeping, breathing, speaking, excreting, and grasping, and opening or closing the eyes. With the light of divine knowledge, they see that it is only the material senses that are moving amongst their objects.

Comment: @ManuKumar I suggest you to convert your comment into answer.